# Query that binds several tables in DAO

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, dao

I'm having trouble writing a query for a webshop i'm making.

You can see my Database structure here.
[Database](http://%20db-fiddle.com/f/kHN1XZH2Mu7zjsPSRGs1hs/0)

[image]

I want a query that returns an array of orders of the user with the size/amount/price from my bvb_orders-design table and that returns the image_path from bvb_design.

This is the query I've made so far

```
SELECT `bvb_orders`.*, `bvb_users`.`id`, `bvb_designs`.*, `bvb_order-designs`.`size`,`bvb_order-designs`.`amount`, `bvb_designs-paintings`.* FROM `bvb_orders`
  INNER JOIN `bvb_order-designs` ON `bvb_order-designs`.`order_id` = `bvb_orders`.`id`
  INNER JOIN `bvb_designs` ON `bvb_designs`.`id` = `bvb_order-designs`.`design_id`
  INNER JOIN `bvb_users` ON `bvb_users`.`id` = `bvb_orders`.`user_id`
  INNER JOIN `bvb_designs-paintings`ON `bvb_designs-paintings`.`design_id` = `bvb_designs`.`id`
    WHERE `bvb_orders`.`user_id` = :id
    GROUP BY `bvb_orders`.`date`
```

This is the result I'm looking for a query that gives al the orders of a User ID

```
+------------+---------------+--------+------+-------+
|    date    |     title     | amount | Size | price |
+------------+---------------+--------+------+-------+
| 2018-06-07 | Eerste werkje |      1 | M    |    10 |
+------------+---------------+--------+------+-------+
```

Thanks

Comment: Your SQL query is written incorrect and will cause invalid results. https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/ .. If you want a better query you should provide table structures (`SHOW CREATE TABLE table`) for every table involved, example data (INSERTS) (place the SQL statements on http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ or https://www.db-fiddle.com/)(or the SQL tables as formatted text ascii data tables in the question) and also include expecteds results as formatted text ascii data table

Comment: This is my database structure https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kHN1XZH2Mu7zjsPSRGs1hs/0

Comment: Expected results would help.and are also required on Stackoverflow

Comment: I've added my result I want :)

Comment: "This is the result I'm looking for a query that gives al the orders of a User ID" Your current query should already do that just remove the `GROUP BY `bvb_orders`.`date`` to get all orders of a user.

Comment: Is there any way to sort the query dates? The newest date at top for example.

Comment: Of course there is. Simply add ``ORDER BY `bvb_orders`.`date` DESC`` at the end of your query. This will give you the latest orders first. If you want the oldest orders first, use `ASC` instead of `DESC`. By the way, you shouldn't use reserved mysql words for column or table names (like `date`, which is also a type in mysql).